# What should I use 'Being' or 'to be' in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one is correct?

1. What's your secret of being closer to women?.
2. What's your secret to be closer to women?.

Should I use 'getting' instead of 'being' or 'to be' and 'close' instead of comparative 'closer'? 
What's your secret of getting close to women?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to phrase as:

- *"What's your secret **for** getting closer to women?"* (i.e. asking a person for their specific approach)
- *"What's **the** secret to getting closer to women?"*  (i.e. asking for a generally-accepted approach that applies to all people)

Note that the question itself *might* be seen as somewhat sketchy, if you were to actually ask it...